# Why does my <select> tag has no data when it is dynamic using selectize.js

Tags: javascript, html, select, selectize.js

When I'm trying to remove the effect of selectize my `<select>` tag contains data, but when I used selectize, my `<select>` tag has no data at all.

***I used selectize.js**

Here's my code in HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" name="item[]" id="item[]" required>
   <option value="" selected="selected">Select Item</option> 
</select>
```

Here's my JS code:

```
$('#item\\[\\]').selectize({
  create: false
});
```

**The *item[]* in html contains data from the database.**

Comment: I understand the desire to have square brackets on the `name` attribute, to allow multiple values from multiple input fields but why have brackets in the `ID` Attribute? I would think it would be more difficult to have unique id attribute values. Is that a selectize thing?

Comment: My id is also dynamic and contains data from the database. I used it as my connection to retrieve data from the database.

Comment: I understand that your _data_ likely has an _id_ field that has various values but I am talking about `<select ... id="item[]"` <-- why do you need brackets in the value (i.e. `item[]`) of the _id_ attribute? *id* attributes should be unique on a page (lest they become superfluous) so if you have multiple elements with that same id attribute value then this will lead to problems. Also, when you say `remove the effect of selectize` - how is that done? do you use the `destroy()` method? Can you create an example (e.g. [this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/s9wwWj7oheK0HaO7NykU?p=preview))?

Comment: I used `id="item[]"` to fetch and loop data from the database. I've also tried to remove those brackets but it has the same result.

Comment: when you say `remove the effect of selectize` - how is that done? do you use the destroy() method? Is your code like [this example](http://plnkr.co/edit/s9wwWj7oheK0HaO7NykU?p=preview)? Please provide more details

Comment: Problem solved sir!  Thank you for your answer ;)